# Seek for a algebro-geometric proof: the group homomorphism $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ is surjective

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

It is a well-known fact that the group homomorphism $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ is surjective.

What I want is a proof by method of algebraic geometry. For example, Let $G= \mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ be the corresponding group scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}/N) \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ gives $G(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow G(\mathbb{Z}/N)$. Then use algebro-geometric method to show that this map is surjective.

Comment: Are you asking about "strong approximation" for simply connected, semisimple algebraic groups?  This was proved over number fields by Kneser and Platonov.   If Borovoi sees this post, he can give you far more detail than I can.

Comment: I doubt that what you are looking for exists since the surjectivity boils down to properties of simply connected Chevalley group schemes over $\mathbb{Z}$ (and fails for things like $\mathrm{GL}_n$). There is a story that Demazure asked Serre and Grothendieck something similar to your question and the answer that eventually emerged is strong approximation and the theory in SGA 3.

Comment: @AStasinski Is there any English reference for the story?

Comment: Not really, but you can start with Gille's "Introduction to reductive group schemes over rings".

Comment: @XTChen - this was explained in my post: There is no map of group schemes $SL(2,Z) \rightarrow SL(2,Z/NZ)$ in general.

Comment: @AStasinski Do you mean this note gives an answer to my question? Or this note just tells the story between Demazure and Serre&Grothendieck?

Comment: @hm2020 In your answer you ask the OP "When you write down your surjection - do you mean the surjection in $R1$ or do you mean something else?". Do I understand correctly that you further proceed as if the OP would answer "Yes, I mean the surjection in $R1$"?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - In the deleted post I answered 2 questions using elementary methods: The case of the surjection $R1$ and the other case: The case about a map of group schemes $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow SL(2, \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @hm2020 I see. Still, I do not see answers to two questions. You finish with "Hence one answer is..." Do you mean that the note following that paragraph contains an answer to another question?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - The note following that paragraph contains answers to two questions: The one on $R1$ and the one on the map of group schemes $SL(2,Z) \rightarrow SL(2,Z/NZ)$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - the new question is diffferent: It asks if any point in $G(Z/NZ)$ comes from a point in $G(Z)$. This was not clear in the original question.

Comment: @hm2020 I see, thanks. So you addressed two possible interpretations of the question which was not clearly formulated by then, and later it turned out the OP had in mind something third, still different from both of your interpretations?

Comment: I deleted a number of comments which were not about the question itself. If anyone would like to discuss the process of deleting answers etc., they are welcome to post on meta.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - I made a guess on what the question was, and answered this question. It seems my post was deleted and then the question changed.  When the asker writes $SL(2, \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ this does usually not mean $G(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ with $G:=Spec(R)$ and $R:=\mathbb{Z}[x_{ij}]/(det(x_{ij})-1)$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - usually $SL(2, \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ means $Spec(A)$ with $A:= \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}[x_{ij}]/(det(x_{ij})-1)$.

Comment: @hm2020: I think you have seriously misunderstood this question and the notation. Firstly, $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ denote groups, not schemes, as they are sets of points of a group scheme. So it is clear that there is no morphism or group schemes between them since they are not schemes. There is a morphism of schemes $\mathrm{SL}(2)_{\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}} \to \mathrm{SL}(2)_{\mathbb{Z}}$ given by inclusion which the OP already knows about.

Comment: Then the OP is asking about whether the fact that the map of groups  $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ is surjective can be proved using tools from algebraic geometry. Your answer and resulting comments do not address this question. Since this is a fact from number theory some number theory should play a role in proving this, but it seems reasonable to suspect there may be a proof using tools from algebraic geometry over $\mathbb{Z}$, which is what the OP's question is about.

Comment: @DanielLoughran - usually when you write $SL(n,R)$ where $R$ is a commutative ring this means $Spec(A)$ with $A:=R[x_{ij}]/(det(x_{ij})-1)$. My post was written partly to ask for a clearification - what did the asker mean? When the moderator delets the  post before the asker has a chance to clearify, this act confuses the entire process of asking and answering questions.

Comment: @hm2020: This is bad notation which should be avoided. For a scheme $X$ over a ring $A$ it is standard notation in algebraic geometry to write $X(A)$ for the set of $A$-points of $X$. This is part of Grothendieck's functorial view of algebraic geometry. I think the notation of the OP is perfectly clear to anyone who knows this result in the context of strong approximation and no further clarification is necessary.

Comment: @DanielLoughran - I do not have any problems with people using a different notation. But when asking a question on this site we avoid many misunderstandings if the asker makes this precise in the question. The problem in this case was that Petersen and others deleted  my post before the asker had any chance of making such a clearification.

Comment: I wrote the following "When you write down your surjection - do you mean the surjection in R1 or do you mean something else?" to ask for a clearification, but this post was deleted before the asker had any chance of responding.

Comment: @hm2020 I must strongly disagree with the asserion that $SL(n,R)$ usually means spectrum of some ring. In fact I have never seen this notation used to denote such a thing, even in algebraic geometry. That notation to me always indicated the mere group of matrices.